# Install an alternative browser on Surface with 32bit Tegra 3 Processor

Tags: microsoft-surface, arm, windows-rt, jailbreak

I found no solution to replace Internet Explorer on my surface 32 Bit ARM-Processor.

I tried to install the [RT Jailbreak Tool for Windows RT 8.0](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2092158) But that one doesn't seem to work on my Surface with Windows **8.1** (it starts o bootup a cmd window and after 2 minutues it shows it cannot fiind a registry entry and closes.)

I tried to install some of the [list of x86 app compiled for ARM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2092348). I found [QupZilla](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2353048), which should run on ARM, but I already were unable to install 7zip on Windows RT by downloading the binaries of 7-zip ARM version from here: http://file.wizrd.tk/7ZARM.zip

How can I install any other browser than IE, like Firefox, Chrome or any other alternative like QupZilla?

Comment: Without them releasing a version for Windows RT you probably cannot.  The ARM processor is not the same as the one that is in a laptop or desktop PC and as a result the ARM based surface tablets run a very cut-down version of Windows. http://www.cnet.com/news/microsoft-bans-firefox-on-arm-based-windows-mozilla-says/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one option available to you - downgrade to Windows RT 8.0, jailbreak it and install the desktop apps you want that have been recompiled for Windows on ARM.